# In Filemaker, after searching *within* search results, how can I return to my previous search results?

Tags: filemaker

I'm creating an inventory database in Filemaker Pro Advanced (v15) for my little café, and I've made a [little red button that appears in the header if any of our items drop down below a certain level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6phv.png), so when I click that button, [it shows just those items that need reordering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5c3M.png).

It performs that action by running a script like so:

```
Go to Layout [ “Inventory Reorders Required” (Inventory) ]
Enter Find Mode [ Pause: Off ] 
Set Field [ Inventory::Availability ; "Reorder Required" ] 
Perform Find [] 
Sort Records [ Restore ; With dialog: Off ]
```

It then goes to a duplicated layout whose only difference (aside from color change) is, **the button changes to a "show all" function**, which is how I want it to act from the main page.

```
Enter Browse Mode [ Pause: Off ]
Go to Layout [ “Inventory” (Inventory) ]
Show All Records
Sort Records [ Restore ; With dialog: Off ]
```

If I do a search—for instance, for "coffee beans,"—clicking that little red button from the search results will narrow the search to just the *coffee beans* that need reordering—NOT all products that need reordering—again, just how I want it to act.

My question is: Like how I have the button set to return to showing *all items* when clicked from the main page, **I'd like it to return to showing *all search results*** when clicked from the search results page. But I can't find any way to do that. My "solution" so far has been to just disable that button from appearing on the search results layout, but it'd sure be a handy feature to have if we can make it work.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but instead of duplicating an entire layout, consider hiding the button when you don't need it - see: http://www.filemaker.com/help/15/fmp/en/#page/FMP_Help%2Fhiding-showing-objects.html%23 Similarly, you can use conditional formatting to change colors of object: http://www.filemaker.com/help/15/fmp/en/#page/FMP_Help%2Fconditional-formatting.html%23

Comment: It is hidden when I don't need it. I duplicated the layout because I changed the colors of everything in the header, including hovers/presses/etc. and because it's just easier for me to fix things by using script triggers onLayoutEnter without the user knowing.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you could open the reorder layout in a new window, preserving your old found set in the background and operating on the new found set in the foreground? Then when the user is done with the reorder window, they can close it (or the button can close the window) and the user will be left with the original found set.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way could be to just open a new window when you click the red button and show your filtered output. Then, just close the window to return to the window with your previous results. In FileMaker 16, you could have used a card window for this also.

Otherwise, http://www.soliantconsulting.com/blog/2016/03/recreating-a-filemaker-found-set describes several methods of restoring found sets.

Comment: What if the button performs a "constrain found set" instead of performing an entirely new search? Is there some way to have the 2nd button *un*constrain the found set afterwards? Because that seems like a feature Filemaker should have, but I'm not finding it. Thanks for the advice! I'm trying to wrap my head around soliantconsulting's piece. For this project, a new window would be a last-resort solution, but I may reach my last resort soon, so that may have to do!

Comment: @LesterNelson There is no way to "unconstrain" the found set without repeating the find criteria that were used to construct the original found set. You could - at least in theory - use the Modify Last Find command to reconstruct them. In practice, that may prove a little more difficult. It would be much simpler to open a new window as suggested.